# RSA-Implementation isn't decrypting correctly

Tags: c++, encryption, rsa, encryption-asymmetric

I like to learn and today I decided to finally implement RSA on my own.
Basically from what I can tell my Code should work and it actually does to a certain extent.

However, even though (according to Internet learning sources) the correct keys are calculated and correctly used I get weird outputs. I checked but couldn't find where the problem is, because calculating by hand yields the same results...

So yeah, here's my `cryptography.cpp`-File:

```cpp
#include "cryptography.h"

bool prime(const unsigned long long n) {
    //max of sqrt(n)
    unsigned long long m = 0.5 * n;

    for(unsigned int i = 2; i <= m; i++) //check every possible divisor
        if(n % i == 0)  //wheter it goes in to n perfectly
            return false;   //n is not prime if such divisor is found

    //if no divisor found
    return true;
}

bool coprime(unsigned long long p, unsigned long long q) {
    //p >= q
    if(q > p) {
        long long t = p;
        p = q;
        q = t;
    }

    //subtract smaller from bigger, keeping gcd
    while(q != 0) {
        unsigned long long r = p % q;
        p = q;
        q = r;
    }

    //gdc == 1
    return p == 1;
}

/**
 * Finds d for:
 * 1 = (d * e) % m
*/
unsigned long long modularInverse(const unsigned long long e, const unsigned long long m) {
    unsigned long long d = 1;
    while(d * e % m != 1)
        d++;
    return d;
}

unsigned long long pow(const unsigned long long base, const unsigned long long exponent) {
    unsigned long long result = 1;
    for(long long i = 0; i < exponent; i++)
        result *= base;
    return result;
}

bool RSA::generateKeys(const unsigned long long p, const unsigned long long q, unsigned long long& n, unsigned long long& d, unsigned long long& e) {
    //p & q have to be primes
    if(!(prime(p) && prime(q)) || p == q)
        return false;

    //n defined as p * q
    n = p * q;

    unsigned long long m = (p - 1) * (q - 1);

    //find e where e and (p - 1)(q - 1) are coprime
    e = 7;
    while(!coprime(m, e))
        e++;

    //1 = (d * e) % (p - 1)(q - 1)
    d = modularInverse(e, m);

    //everything worked
    return true;
}

unsigned long long RSA::encrypt(const unsigned long long message, const unsigned long long e, const unsigned long long n) {
    return pow(message, e) % n;
}

unsigned long long RSA::decrypt(const unsigned long long encryptedMessage, const unsigned long long d, const unsigned long long n) {
    return pow(encryptedMessage, d) % n;
}
```

Just to be sure here's how it's used in `main.cpp`:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "cryptography.h"

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    unsigned long long n, d, e;
    if(!RSA::generateKeys(7, 13, n, d, e))
        return -1;
    std::cout << "n: " << n << std::endl;
    std::cout << "d: " << d << std::endl;
    std::cout << "e: " << e << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::endl;
    unsigned long long message;
    std::cin >> message;
    std::cout << "Message: " << message << std::endl;
    unsigned long long encryptedMessage = RSA::encrypt(message, e, n);
    std::cout << "Encrypted Message: " << encryptedMessage << std::endl;
    unsigned long long decryptedMessage = RSA::decrypt(encryptedMessage, d, n);
    std::cout << "Decrypted Message: " << decryptedMessage << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Do not use `pow` in the numeric arithmetic.

Comment: @S.M. The `pow()` function is (hopefully) the `unsigned long long pow(const unsigned long long base, const unsigned long long exponent)` posted.  That looks OK.

Comment: Use GMP, do not reinvent the wheel!

Comment: @S.M. I'm sorry, but unfortunately I don't understand. Which of the 2 Calls (in encrypt & decrypt) is wrong and (if you know) why

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation

Comment: @kelalaka The entire purpose of this code is stated as learning how to do RSA encryption and decryption: " implement RSA on my own".

Comment: This is bad, though:  `unsigned long long m = 0.5 * n;`  That's likely to result in a value for `m` that's not `n/2`.  Don't use floating point values in cryptographic code...

Comment: The you obviously doing a very bad way; finding primes - no sieving, inverse - is not with extgcd, pow - is not modular square and multiply that will fail you!

Comment: @AndrewHenle: It's probably ok but for a bad reason: it's exact for small values of n and for large values using n/2 is way way larger than necessary.

Comment: @President James K. Polk Although I obviously see the connection to the topic/problem, but I wasn't having Overflow-Errors. Thanks anyway; interesting insights

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk I didn't even really analyze it - it's a floating-point calculation used in integer-based cryptographic code. To me that's an automatic red card/flag on the play depending on your preferred form of football.

Comment: @TK36: How do you know? Integer overflow is silent.

Comment: @TK36 Is it?  How do you know?  You've benchmarked and profiled both versions?  Or are you just basing that on what you've been told?

Comment: Small unsafe RSA keys are 512 bits long,  current safe keys  are 2048 bits and to looking to the future we should start to consider 4096 and 8192 bit keys.  So your starting place is multi-precision integer arithmetic to handle integers up to 4K bits.

Comment: @Richard Critten it's not for a real application, especially not for a secure one. it's just playing around with the concept and I don't think worrying about key-size is neccessary for it

Comment: use `>> 1` instead of `/2` though a good compiler will convert it to `>>1`

Comment: @TK36 multi-precision integer maths is fun and will be useful on many other projects - it's also a good test of coding and testing skills.

Comment: @RichardCritten you mean implementing Systems that can store big Integers yourself? I acctually considered it and I will do it some time :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @President James K. Polk correctly guessed the Problem was a silent Integer-Overflow. Also to anyone stuck on this: too high encryption-data-integers can cause problems on small primes easily.

I used [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) to replace `pow(a, b) % c` in the `encrypt` & `decrypt` Method with a call to `modularPow(a, b, c)`:

```cpp
unsigned long long modularPow(const unsigned long long base, const unsigned long long exponent, const unsigned long long modulus) {
    unsigned long long result = 1;
    for(unsigned long long i = 0; i < exponent; i++) {
        result *= base;
        result %= modulus;
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: A slight intriduction for you: [Efficient function/algorithm/method to do modular exponentiation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/75408/18298)